# Paragraph counter

Tags: bash, shell, paragraph

I have a text file and I wrote a script for Linux where it counts all the characters (with spaces) the number of lines and words. I also have to write something that counts the number of paragraphs but I don't know how. If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

This is my script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

is_text_file() {
  if [[ $(grep -c -P '[\x01-\x7F]' "$1") -gt 0 ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 -file FILE_PATH [-occurrences NUMBER]"
  exit 1
fi

while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -file)
      file="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    -occurrences)
      occurrences="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid flag: $1"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

if ! is_text_file "$file"; then
  echo "The specified file is not a text file."
  exit 1
fi

word_count=$(cat "$file" | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | wc -w)
line_count=$(cat "$file" | grep -c '^')
character_count=$(cat "$file" | wc -c)
paragraph_count=$(awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } { print NF }' "$file")

echo "Word count: $word_count"
echo "Line count: $line_count"
echo "Character count: $character_count"
echo "Paragraph count: $paragraph_count"

if [ -n "$occurrences" ]; then
  echo "Most frequent words:"
  cat "$file" | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | tr -d '[:punct:]' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n "$occurrences"
fi
```

This is my text file:

```
This is a sample text file.  
It contains some words and paragraphs.

Feel free to add more, content for testing.
```

It should say that there are 2 paragraphs, but it says 1.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Don't cat single files. Make them arguments or redirect them, as in `grep -c '^' < "$file"`. This saves expensive forks and pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appears you *may* have DOS line endings. That will interfere with using awk in [paragraph mode](https://learnbyexample.github.io/tips/cli-tip-9/) which is the easist way to solve your issue.

Given:

```
$ printf "This is a sample text file.\r\nIt contains some words and paragraphs.\r\n\r\nFeel free to add more, content for testing.">file
```

You can use GNU awk or a recent awk that supports more than one character for a record separator:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n(\r?\n)+"} END{print NR}' file
```

(Note: Setting `RS="\r?\n(\r?\n)+"` is not the same as `RS=""` See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html#Multiple-Line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772568/298607))

If you want to use classic Paragraph Mode in awk (with `RS=""`), use a method to remove the `\r` at the line endings. The best is either a nested awk or sed:

```
$ sed 's/\r$//' file | awk -v RS= 'END{print NR}'
$ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}1' file | awk -v RS= 'END{print NR}'
```

Or Ruby:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts $<.read.split(/\R\R+/).length' file
```

Any of those should print `2` regardless of DOS or Unix line endings.

If you want total paragraphs, words, and punctuation marks I would do that in Ruby:

```
ruby -e '
inp=$<.read
para=inp.split(/\R\R+/)
words=para.map{|p| p.split}
puts "Paragraphs=#{para.length}"
puts "words=#{words.map(&:length).sum}"
puts "Punctuation marks=#{inp.scan(/[[:punct:]]/).length}"
' file
```

Or in awk:

```
awk '
BEGIN{RS="\r?\n(\r?\n)+"} 
{
    p+=gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "&")
    split($0, words)
    w+=length(words)
}
END{printf("Paragraphs=%s\nwords=%s\nPunctuation marks=%s\n", NR, w, p)}' file
```

Either prints:

```
Paragraphs=2
words=20
Punctuation marks=4
```

Either of those is easily modified (based on that skeleton) to count whatever you want to count in the text.

Comment: Very nice. When using `?` in `RS` it's always worth mentioning the caveat that gawk may match the text before `?` but not after (rare, but no guarantee it won't happen). See [4.1.2 Record Splitting with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html) with the paragraph beginning "*If you set `RS` to a regular expression that allows optional trailing text,...*" (just before the first Caveat box)

Comment: Alternative `awk -v RS="\n|\r\n" '! /^$/ {recs++} END{print recs}' file`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of a *paragraph*.

With the assumption that paragraphs are separated by one or more empty lines this should do it:

```
awk -v RS='' 'END{print NR}' your_file
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work unfortunately. It says 1 paragraph.

Comment: That happens, if your file has Windows newlies, ie. `\r\n` instead of just `\n` used in Un*ces. In that case use: `awk -v RS="\r\n(\r\n)+" ...` ie. _two or more newlines separate records (or paragraphs)_.

Comment: Previous works in GNU awk, mawk and Busybox awk but failed in `awk version 20121220`. I did not test in MacOS awk as my Macbook was collecting dust under the bed and uncharged.